# Where are the rest of the White Walkers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

The White Walkers take

> Craster's sons and turn them into more White Walkers.

There was a scene where a White Walker

> converts a baby into another White Walker,

surrounded by other White Walkers. There should be an army of White Walkers by now, not considering the wights. But when fighting with the

> Wildlings/Night’s Watch/Brotherhood Without Banners/random tag-alongs and the dragons

and during

> the destruction of The Wall

too few White Walkers were shown. Where are the rest of them?

Comment: TL;DR: We don't know how many white walkers there are but what leads you to the assumption that there should be an army of them?

Comment: Side note: Just because something isn't shown doesn't mean it hasn't happened. Note: we only ever see 4 or 5 white walkers with the Night King yet we've seen a few others be killed so it makes sense to think there are more than are shown at any one time.

Comment: And how many is “an army”, exactly?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Your note is proven by the Walker who leads the scouting party (where Jon and his Merry Men end up capturing a wight). Many scouting parties could exists, and then there's still the possibility of Walkers being sent on other mission (or simply commanding the troops on the ground, as we see happen when the army arrives at the Wall, the Walkers seem to lead a platoon each)

Comment: @Flater And also in Bran's raven warging we see The WW's stationed at intervals along the lines of wights.